# Consistent USB device adapter naming on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, udev, dev

I have a USB port into which I insert all sorts of different USB disks over time. The kernel does not consistently allocate the same device for it, so I have to go hunt after each insert. How can I always get the same device name?

Note that driving this from the UUID or such does not work, because I use the same port for different disks. It's not the disk I want to consistently name, it's the current disk that's in a consistent port.

I had been hoping there would be some kind of `/sys/…/controllerX/…/portY/…` path that identifies the USB port, rather than the disk, but hunting for it I did not find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/disk/by-path/` is what you seek.

E.g. my pendrive in a "certain" USB port was:

```
pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdc
```

After disconnecting and plugging into another port it was:

```
pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdc
```

And yet in another port:

```
pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdc
```

I left it there, plugged another pendrive into the "certain" port. Now these two are:

```
pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdc
pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0 -> ../../sdd
```

Note the `sdd` (another pendrive) has the same "by-path" name the `sdc` had when it was in the "certain" USB port. The full path in the filesystem is

```
/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
```

in my case. Its first partition is

```
/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
```

I believe this solves your problem.

Comment: Duh, I didn't think of looking under /dev.